# how to get value through one class to another through intent?

Tags: java, android

i m new to android.i am trying to make a quiz app which has categories. i am passing different int value on click of each category i want to use that value in my Questionactivity class so that when first button is clicked only first 10 questions will run and on click of second button 10 to 20 questions will run.

```
    package com.example.chaitanya.myquiz;

     import java.util.List;
      import java.util.Random;
     import java.util.Timer;
     import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

     import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
     import android.annotation.TargetApi;
     import android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.graphics.Typeface;
      import android.media.MediaPlayer;
      import android.os.Build;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.os.CountDownTimer;
      import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
      import android.util.Log;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.TextView;

      import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;


  public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {
  List<Question> quesList;
  int score = 0;
  Random r = new Random();
  Question currentQ;
  TextView txtQuestion, times, scored;
  Button button1, button2, button3;
  CounterClass timer;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    int qid = intent2.getIntExtra("qid",10);
    QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);  // my question bank class
    quesList = db.getAllQuestions();  // this will fetch all quetonall   
    questions
    currentQ = quesList.get(qid); // the current question

    txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
    // the textview in which the question will be displayed

    // the three buttons,

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    // the textview in which score will be displayed
    scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

    // the timer
    times = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);


    // method which will set the things up for our game
    setQuestionView();
    times.setText("00:00:30");

    // A timer of 30 seconds to play for, with an interval of 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
    timer = new CounterClass(30000, 1000);
    timer.start();

    // button click listeners
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // passing the button text to other method
            // to check whether the anser is correct or not
            // same for all three buttons
            getAnswer(button1.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button2.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button3.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    int qid = intent2.getIntExtra("qid", 10);
    if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {

        // if conditions matches increase the int (score) by 1
        // and set the text of the score view
        score++;
        scored.setText("Score : " + score);

    } else {

        // if unlucky start activity and finish the game
        timer.cancel();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                ResultActivity.class);
        // passing the int value
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    if (qid < 60) {

        // if questions are not over then do this
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        setQuestionView();
    } else {
        // if over do this
        timer.cancel();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                ResultActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        times.setText("Time is up");
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                ResultActivity.class);
        timer.cancel();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format(
                "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                        - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        .toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                        -   
           TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        .toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        times.setText(hms);
    }


}

private void setQuestionView() {
    Random r = new Random();
    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    int qid = intent2.getIntExtra("qid", 10);
    switch (qid) {
        case 10:
            // the method which will put all things together
            txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
            button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
            button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
            button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
            qid = (r.nextInt(10) + 1);
        case 20:
            txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
            button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
            button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
            button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
            qid = (r.nextInt(20) + 11);
        case 30:
            txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
            button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
            button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
            button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
            qid = (r.nextInt(30) + 21);
        }

          }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show me error log?

Comment: It is really hard to understand your problem with our any logging

Answer (score 0):

You need Internet permission to access network.

Add these permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Details: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

the exception is raised from null pointer, the starting intent of your activity has no extra bundle

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to     
           invoke virtual method 'double 
        android.os.Bundle.getDouble(java.lang.String)' on a null             
              object reference
              at    
              com.example.chaitanya.calculatornew.
              MainActivity.findtheweather(MainActivity.java:27)
```